# Text display in infowindow inconsistant

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I have a google map with markers and infowindowsfew created. The text for the infowindows is coming from an XML document. When the map is displayed, some of the infowindows display all the text and some others do not. For example, some of the longer texts display the contents as written in the XML while some of the shorter text string don't display the last four characters. All the infowindows should end with Trocken Bach. Below is an example (note: I cannot include images yet. You can view this at: http://tbk-dk.com/dogMapMarkers/markers.html):

Incomplete display: Cira vom Trocken but the XML document contains the text Cira vom Trocken Bach which is shorter than the next example.

Complete display: Franci vom Trocken Bach displays full text as it is found in the XML doc yet this text is longer than the previous one.

Below is the code I have developed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map").css({
        height: 700,
        width: 800
});
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(xxxx, xxxx);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $("#showmarkers").ready(function(e){
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('dog-markers.xml');
  });
});

var MYMAP = {
  map: null,
    bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();

        // create a new LatLng point for the marker
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

        // extend the bounds to include the new point
        MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: MYMAP.map
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
});


        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
    });
});
}
```

Thank you all for helping with this problem.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9txchx/)

Comment: Where is the "Cira vom Trocken Bach" marker?  I don't see any issues in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9txchx/embedded/result/).  Correction, I only see an issue on the first infowindow opened, after that it seems fine.

Comment: If you look at the markers in Germany you will see an example of what I tried to describe.

Comment: I don't see that behavior (at least in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9txchx/embedded/result/)).  Do you see it in the fiddle?  If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: I do see it in the fiddle. I am using Firefox 34.0.5.

Comment: I see in Chrome there is scroll option so in that browser I guess I need to size the infowindow. Any chance I can get some help with that? Maybe that will solve both problems.

Comment: Is it only the first time the infowindow is opened?

Comment: For @geocodezip - when I open it in IE, Chrome and Firefox, some still show full and some partial, even after the first one is open. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @geocodezip. Wanted to let you know that for some reason when I view your fiddle in Firefox, the problem still exists, but not in the other browsers. But I downloaded the code, and ran it from all the browsers and it works as it should. Thank you. One last request if I may, can you show me how the js code would access the XML code in a folder up one level in the file structure? Again, I can't tell you how much I appreciate this.

Comment: This is my first attempt at doing anything with Google Maps and I am not sure how to go about connecting the external XML file from within your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the property white-space:nowrap to the strong tag

Comment: I tried that but when I opened in Chrome, it still wrapped. This is what that line of code is after I did that. Is it correct?
    var html='<strong white-space:nowrap>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;

Comment: No... Change your code into this: var html='<strong style="white-space:nowrap">'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address; and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to work correctly in all the major browsers except Firefox. I am still having problems seeing the 'Bach' text in the infowindow of about 1/2 of them. any other suggestions?

Comment: try to add a div around him with style="width:100%" if it doesn't work, use a fixed width that will fit all the names... example: var html = '<div style="width:100%"><strong style="white-space:nowrap">'+name+'</strong><br/>'+address+'</div>'; or change the width:100% of the previous example into something like width:300px I add the white-space:nowrap attribute to your jsfiddle and it works well also on Firefox.. just try to delete the cache or press CTRL+F5. It will do the work